# Multiple forms calling same javascript function

Tags: javascript, forms, events, scope

I have a page with multiple forms calling the same javascript function.  Each form posts a picture to a given database item and has an ID that references that database item (e.g. id="form123"). When the user selects a picture, they should get a "spinner" (indicating file uploading) and then the form should submit.

Problem is, no matter which form gets an onchange event (from selecting a picture on the client), the browser always passes variables for the first form with "onchange" on the page.

```js
function submitForm(formId, spinner) {
    console.log(formId);
    console.log(spinner);
    setDisplay(document.getElementById(spinner), 'inline-block');
    return document.forms.formId.submit();
};

function setDisplay(element, value) {
    return element.style.display = value;
};
```

```html
<form method="post" name="form28236" id="form28236" class="submit-image" action="/image/new" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="hidden" name="on" value="28236">
   <label for="image-file">Add photos</label>
   <input type="file" id="image-file" name="image" onchange="submitForm('form28236', 'spinner28236')">
   <div id="spinner28236" class="spinner"></div>
</form>
```

```
Console:
form28330
spinner28330
```

Note that the console is not logging the same form ID or spinner id that should be passed to the javascript function. The result is that the "spinner" displays for the wrong form (the first on the page) and no form actually gets submitted.

Comment: I copied your snipped and duplicated the form markup, changing the last digit on all the ids of the second form. It worked as intended for me. The obvious thing would be checking the arguments in the submitForm call in the onchange event, but I'm assuming you've already done that. Can you post a snippet with multiple formats so that actually reproduces the error?

Comment: This line looks wrong: `return document.forms.formId.submit();`.  It should probably be `return document.forms[formId].submit();`.  Not sure if that's your root issue though.

Comment: There is only one form in your example, so its hard to see where the spinner problem is coming from. The problem with the form submit is that pointed out by @Noah Freitas

Comment: I solved it myself.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the form submit is in this line:

```
document.forms.formId.submit();
```

This syntax would work if your form was actually named `"formId"`. However, instead you have a variable `formId` that holds the respective id, so you have to do it like this:

```
document.forms[formId].submit();
```

Maybe it becomes clearer when you see that your variable only substitutes the actual name. This would also work to access a specific form:

```
document.forms['form28236'].submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that I didn't have a unique ID for the `<input type="file">` and the corresponding `<label for="unique-id">`.  I was using the `<label>` as a button for the input (and hiding the input). But since it wasn't a unique ID, the browser was just going with the first `<input>` with that ID on the page.